# "You should only initialize MvxBindingSingletonCache once" error when have several test classes

Tags: mvvmcross

I run into a strange exception. In my test project, I use Moq, xUnit, and MvvmCross.Tests.
When I run my tests from one class - everything works just fine. When I run tests from 2 classes I get MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxException.

I have 2 identical (initialization is identical) classes VitalsDataTests and GetReimbursedTests:

```
    public class VitalsDataTests : MvxIoCSupportingTest
    {
        public VitalsDataTests()
        {
            base.Setup();
        }
        protected MockDispatcher MockDispatcher
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        protected override void AdditionalSetup()
        {
            MockDispatcher = new MockDispatcher();

            Ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxViewDispatcher>(MockDispatcher);
            Ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxMainThreadDispatcher>(MockDispatcher);
            Ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxMainThreadAsyncDispatcher>(MockDispatcher);
        }
       ...
     }
```

Here is my MockDispatcher:

```
    public class MockDispatcher
        : MvxMainThreadDispatcher
        , IMvxViewDispatcher
    {
        public readonly List<MvxViewModelRequest> Requests;
        public readonly List<MvxPresentationHint> Hints;
        public MockDispatcher()
        {
            if (Hints == null) Hints = new List<MvxPresentationHint>();
            if (Requests == null) Requests = new List<MvxViewModelRequest>();
        }
        public override bool IsOnMainThread { get; }

        public Task<bool> ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint)
        {
            Hints.Add(hint);
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }

        public async Task ExecuteOnMainThreadAsync(Action action, bool maskExceptions = true)
        {
            await Task.Run(action);
        }

        public async Task ExecuteOnMainThreadAsync(Func<Task> action, bool maskExceptions = true)
        {
            await Task.Run(action);
        }

        public override bool RequestMainThreadAction(Action action, bool maskExceptions = true)
        {
            action();
            return true;
        }

        public Task<bool> ShowViewModel(MvxViewModelRequest request)
        {
            Requests.Add(request);
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
    }
```

What I tried:
Clearing MvxSingleton and MvxBindingSingletonCache singletons in the constructor of each class before I call base.Setup():
MvxSingleton.ClearAllSingletons();
MvxBindingSingletonCache.ClearAllSingletons();

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this error by adding XUnit Collection Attribute for each test class, like this:

```
[Collection("ViewModels")]
public class GetReimbursedTests : BaseTest
{
     ...
}
```